# Сброс авторизации Mail.ru

Tags: delphi, cookie, авторизация

Доброго времени суток! Сделал авторизацию в mail.ru c сохранением cookies. Но по не ведомой мне причине происходит logout по происшествию 7 дней и отображается страница просто входа. Подскажите как решить столь не простую задачку?

```
var 
  p: TStringList;
begin 
  p.Add('Domain=' + domain);
  p.Add('Login=' + parse(femail, '', '@'));
  p.Add('Password=' + fpassword);
  p.Add('new_auth_form=1');
  p.Add('saveauth=1');
  txt := fhttp.Post('auth.mail.ru/cgi-bin/auth?from=splash', p);
end;
```

Comment: Рискну предположить, что срок действия куки истекает. Если нет - нужно искать ошибку в 17 строке. На всякий случай - расшифрую: это иносказание, вы предоставили слишком мало информации. Нет ни перечня инструментов/компонентов, которыми пользуетесь, нет кода... Посмотрите на свой вопрос с точки зрения человека, который не в теме - что, чем и как вы делаете. Что он сможет понять? И сможет ли дать ответ?

Comment: Откуда информация про полгода?

Comment: @zed `Max-Age=15551995; Expires=Tue, 20-Dec-2016 07:23:38 GMT`   `Max-Age=7775995; Expires=Wed, 21-Sep-2016 07:23:38 GMT`

Comment: 7 дней похоже на то что внешний IP-адрес меняется (у провайдеров обычно DHCP Lease = 7 дней как раз) и куки становится невалидным.

Comment: @Alekcvp А как же тогда браузер работает, у меня почта в опере уже не перывй месяц нормально работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Народ как оказалось, все очень просто, чем я думал. Багуля была у меня, и связанна она с кукой SDC. По факту разлогирование не было. Для тех кто делает клиент под облако mail.ru, если столкнутся с этим, просто обновите куку вот этой ссылкой (https://auth.mail.ru/sdc?from=https://cloud.mail.ru/home)